# Javascript Map displaying multiple items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some code which displays some data on a table be adding a new `<tr><td>...`

It currently display's only 1 item which is name ....

See below:

```
<tbody>
  {
     props.names.map( ({name}, i) => <tr key={i}><td>{ name }</td></tr> )
  }
</tbody>
```

If I have more items to display... for example:

```
id, name, lastname etc
```

For example:

```
<td>{ id }</td>
<td>{ name }</td>
<td>{ lastname }</td>
```

How do I modify the code above so I can do that?

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53649564/edit) then `[<>]` the snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: It depends where you have this information stored. If your `props.names` is an array of objects with properties called id, name etc then yes, it's easily possible by modifying the code you have. (PS since you appear to be using React it might be a good idea to use the "react" tag)

Comment: Is that JSX? Are you working with React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if names is an array with many name objects. As an example, If a single name object looks like this? {"id":1, "name": "Tim Ering", "lastname": "Ering"}

Try this?

```
props.names.map( (nameObj, i) => ( 
<tr key={i}>
   <td>{ nameObj.id }</td>
   <td>{ nameObj.name }</td>
   <td>{ nameObj.lastname }</td>
 </tr> 
))
```

But I don't know why just props. I thought that would be this.props.names

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try:

```
props.names.map( ({id, name, lastname}, i) => ( 
    <tr key={i}>
       <td>{ id }</td>
       <td>{ name }</td>
       <td>{ lastname }</td>
     </tr> 
  ))
)
```

Plus this looks like react Js and not javascript, you should change your tags to get more pertinent response/help !